# How to replace variable result with different text HTML

Tags: html, variables

I'm trying to translate a HTML document into another language but am hitting a barrier. Is there any way i can replace the value of a certain variable into another value? That for a few different variable results.

For example, in my document {invoice_type} returns either "Invoice" or "Estimate"... I'd like to replace "Invoice" with "Remisión" and "Estimate" with "Cotización"

Please let me know if there is anything that would make it work

Here's the code I'm talking about "{invoice_type}" will return Invoice or Estimate and I need to replace those values within my code

```html
<div style="color: #000000; font-size: 26px; padding-bottom: 5px; text-transform: capitalize;">{invoice_type}</div>
{invoice_date}<br />
<div style="text-transform: capitalize;">{invoice_type} #: {invoice_id}<br /> Saldo: {invoice_balance}</div>
```

Comment: <div style="color: #000000; font-size: 26px; padding-bottom: 5px; text-transform: capitalize;">{invoice_type}</div>
{invoice_date}<br />
<div style="text-transform: capitalize;">{invoice_type} #: {invoice_id}<br /> Saldo: {invoice_balance}</div>

Comment: Dont't comment additional code, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58013123/edit) button

Comment: Added the code in comment since it didn't appear in the question

Comment: You have to format the code properly, especially with html as it will simply be rendered otherwise

Comment: The code you are providing is not html. This code is being compiled via a backend server. We will need to know what backend stack you are using.

Comment: As for your question, HTML does not have variables, so where does `{invoice_type}` come from or how will html be parsed? the translation should be done when the HTML is rendered and the variables are replaced

Comment: @avcajaraville I do not own the web application, the only code I have access to is the Invoice Template, here's a link of the information of the application: https://www.whatruns.com/website/portal.busybench.com

Comment: @empiric isn't there any way to tell the code if {invoice_type} returns a certain value to replace it with a different one? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm very inexperienced

Comment: Without information about how the html is processed/rendered there is no way of telling. If you the only thing you have access to is the HTML template I'm afraid there is nothing you can do (excpet for hardcoding the words which is probably not what you want)

Comment: @empiric For now that is probably what I will have to do now... Just have two different text files for the invoice and estimate and change the HTML code for whatever I want to use at the moment! Thanks for your help